# "for the benefit of", на благо vs для?

Tags: узус

I've learned that when using "*for*", when meaning "*benefit from*", you would use "*для* + gen". But I've also just learned "*на благо*", meaning the same thing. Are they synonyms? How are they different?

Answer (score 2):

Translation of **`for the benefit of`** as **`на благо/пользу`**, **`для/ради блага/пользы`** is more accurate than the simple **`для`**.

That said, context is important, and so due to stylistic differences between the languages there could be cases where **`для`** would fit better.

As far as the difference in meaning is concerned, it's much the same as the difference between that of their English counterparts.

**`Для`** has a purely utilitarian purpose and meaning, denoting satisfaction of some type of need or requirement. **`На благо/пользу`**, **`для/ради блага/пользы`** specifically stress the benefit expected from such satisfaction. And they sound rather solemn and exalted so to speak.

<sup>The two mentioned phrases differ in the way they interact with their indirect object in a sentence. If you're interested in details, please put a note in the comments and i'll expand the answer.</sup>